# LibreOffice: Document name in title bar?

Tags: unity, libreoffice, globalmenu

Is it possible to place the title of the working document in the title bar of LibreOffice Writer like in MS Office?

Would certainly make switching between similar-looking documents easier.

Comment: This should be a problem with Unity's global menu, it works for me with the Xfce desktop.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, isn't that the case? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/title.png

Comment: Yeah, like that. I've never had it, menus are set tu appear in window, not globally. How can I adjust that?

Comment: @Mookey: Could you post a screenshot of how it looks at your end?

Comment: Just the "File, Edit, View, ....".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing a screenshot this is my best guess.

May be you have your current settings like the one below in your Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior:

[image]

This will always show the Menus (like File, Edit, View, etc.

Change the settings to something like:

[image]

So that you can see the window title. You can see the menus on mouse hovering.

Comment: That's it, mine was Always displayed. Thanks a million!

Comment: I want both displayed all the time.